# JavaScript: Remove HTML Tags, Modify Tags/Text, and Insert Tags Back In

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I am trying to find a way to remove all tags in an HTML document, store their location, modify the remaining text, then reinsert the tags where they belong.

**Key Points**

- I need to insert the tags back in again later, thus I need to store the location of each tag

  - Therefore, DOMParser as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript/47140708#47140708) will not work
- This will be done on external websites, not my own
- The regex suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822464/3006096) (`/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm`) will work, but it also falsely captures `<` or `>` included the html

  - Example: https://regexr.com/3npfv
- It seems this works: https://regexr.com/3npgn (`/<[^<|>]*>/g`), but I read that using regex is not a great way to parse html. Are there cases where this would fail?

The full code:

```
function foo() {
    var elementHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
    var tags = [];
    var tagLocations = [];
    //var htmlTagRegEx =/<{1}\/{0,1}\w+>{1}/;
    var htmlTagRegEx =/<[^<]*>/;

    //Strip the tags from the elementHtml and keep track of them
    var htmlTag;
    while (htmlTag = elementHtml.match(htmlTagRegEx)) {
        console.log('htmlTag: ', htmlTag);
        tagLocations[tagLocations.length] = elementHtml.search(htmlTagRegEx);
        tags[tags.length] = htmlTag;
        elementHtml = elementHtml.replace(htmlTag, '');
    }
}
```

---

### **EDIT**

To avoid confusion, here follows a detailed explanation of what I want to accomplish:

Search for a string in the text of a whole (external) website (not including the tags), then change the styling (e.g. color) of those instances if found.

Here is my attempt:

```
    function highlightInElement(elementId, text) {
        var elementHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
        var tags = [];
        var tagLocations = [];
        //var htmlTagRegEx =/<{1}\/{0,1}\w+>{1}/;
        var htmlTagRegEx =/<[^<]*>/;
        //Strip the tags from the elementHtml and keep track of them
        var htmlTag;
        while (htmlTag = elementHtml.match(htmlTagRegEx)) {
            //console.log('htmlTag: ', htmlTag);
            tagLocations[tagLocations.length] = elementHtml.search(htmlTagRegEx);
            tags[tags.length] = htmlTag;
            elementHtml = elementHtml.replace(htmlTag, '');
        }
        console.log('elementHtml: ', elementHtml);

        //Search for the text in the stripped html
        var textLocation = elementHtml.search(text);
        if (textLocation) {
            //Add the highlight
            var highlightHTMLStart = '<span class="highlight">';
            var highlightHTMLEnd = '</span>';
            elementHtml = elementHtml.replace(text, highlightHTMLStart + text + highlightHTMLEnd);

            //plug back in the HTML tags
            var textEndLocation = textLocation + text.length;
            for (let i = tagLocations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var location = tagLocations[i];
                if (location > textEndLocation) {
                    location += highlightHTMLStart.length + highlightHTMLEnd.length;
                } else if (location > textLocation) {
                    location += highlightHTMLStart.length;
                }
                elementHtml = elementHtml.substring(0, location) + tags[i] + elementHtml.substring(location);
            }
        }

        //Update the html of the element
        document.body.innerHTML = elementHtml;
    }

    highlightInElement(document.documentElement, fooInputTxt.value);
```

Comment: If you modify the text, how will you know where to reinsert the tags?

Comment: Obligatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/746736

Comment: @JeremyThille I am saving the location of the tags, so just inserting it back in according to that position. That is the second (non-related) part of the code, not shown above.

Comment: Are you want to replace or modify only text part of tag ? If yes then possible using node of element

Comment: If you are going to put the html tags back, `var htmlChunk = original.split('<');`. Loop over and perform the text modification on each `htmlChunk` (after the `>`), then put it all back together.

Comment: I actually want to edit both the tag and the text.

Comment: That still doesn’t explain (at least to me), why using a DOM parser would not work ...?

Comment: @CBroe Please share if you know how to use DOMParser to remove all tags, find a certain substring in the remaining text, then surround that text with a styling tag (`<span style="color: yellow">....</span>`), then put it all back together

Comment: Can you at least explain why you’d want to insist on that remove-first-only-to-add-again-later approach to begin with? A few examples for what exactly you want to convert into what would also not go amiss.

Comment: @CBroe Apologies if it was confusing. I added a new section with additional detail.

Comment: I would say treat Html file as an XML file and it will become easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To avoid confusion, here follows a detailed explanation of what I want to accomplish: Search for a string in the text of a whole (external) website (not including the tags), then change the styling (e.g. color) of those instances if found.

Then that's exactly what you should do :)

First, build a recursive function to traverse the DOM and get all the text nodes:

```
function findTextNodes(node, ret) {
    var c = node.childNodes, i, l = c.length;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        switch(c[i].nodeType) {
            case 1: // element node
                findTextNodes(c[i], ret);
                break;
            case 3: // text node
                ret.push(c[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
var textNodes = [];
findTextNodes(document.body, textNodes);
```

Now that you have an array of all the text nodes in the document, you can begin searching them for your target.

```
function searchTextNodes(nodes, search) {
    var results = [], l = nodes.length, i,
        regex = new RegExp(search,'i'), match,
        span;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        while( (match = nodes[i].nodeValue.search(regex)) > -1) {
            nodes[i] = nodes[i].splitText(match);
            span = document.createElement('span');
            span.classList.add('highlight');
            nodes[i].parentNode.insertBefore(span, nodes[i]);
            nodes[i].splitText(search.length);
            span.appendChild(nodes[i]);
            nodes[i] = span.nextSibling;
        }
    }
}
searchTextNodes(textNodes, fooInputTxt.value);
```

And... that's it! For extra credit, here's how to "undo" the search:

```
function undoSearch(root) {
    var nodes = root.querySelectorAll("span.highlight"),
        l = nodes.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        nodes[i].parentNode.replaceChild(nodes[i].firstChild, nodes[i]);
    }
    root.normalize();
}
undoSearch(document.body);
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35L5seL9/1/)

Comment: Brilliant! Modifying the DOM directly, I had not thought about that.

Comment: The only question I had: The remove function is stripping away all <span class="highlight"> nodes. Is there any way to remove only the ones we actually inserted? I guess we could save the `span` nodes down in a list when we add it. Then `replaceChild(span.firstChild, span)`?

Comment: You'd be better off using a more unique class name, honestly. But yes, you could keep a list of inserted nodes and just run the replacement on them.

Comment: I managed to get the removal to work :). A couple of follow-up questions if I may:

1) What do you mean by unique class name?
2) What if the search word includes a reserved regex character ([, (, ^, etc.)
3) What if I wanted to include only exact matches (i.e. not those where the search word is inside another word)? I tried this: `var searchString = '(\\W|^)' + search + '(\\W|$)'` and then `var regex = new RegExp(searchString, 'i');` (also remembering to update the `length` reference, further down). It did not work, any idea why?

Comment: 1) `<span class="magnus-search-highlight">` would be "more unique" and less likely to conflict with other things. 2) You'll have to escape those. With a bit of rewriting you can make it work with arbitrary regexes though, which is cool. 3) Use `\b` before and after to indicate a word boundary.

Comment: I deleted some old comments I figured out of. My only question now is: `/\b\\me\b\i` does not work to search for `\me` or `_me`, because `\b` is boundary between word and non-word. I guess, all characters are part of a word, except for perhaps space, period, comma, parenthesis, question mark and exclamation mark (did I forget any?). How do we capture that instead?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, indeed... Especially since JavaScript does not have lookbehinds. If it had lookbehinds you could just do `(?<[ .,()?!])` (with your list of "non-word" symbols). Your best bet might be to check if the first character of the search is a word-character or not (using `\w`) and only add `\b` if it is indeed a word-character. Do the same for the last character and the end

Comment: Would it not then also catch `a\me` (i.e. any char in front of `\me`) and we are back to square one of not finding complete/exact words. Hmmmm, I have been trying to think about it from many angles but struggling..

Comment: Unfortunately you're in a difficult spot of needing to define more broadly "what is a word?"